# iOS memory leakage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I got a old project from client and it is not using navigation. It changes rootViewController every time.

It has a `BaseViewController` with some `NSString` objects, `Dictionary` objects, `extern NSString* const` objects. All viewControllers are subClassed from `BaseViewController`.

In Appdelegate it has a some NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary etc. It stores info of last viewController in array.

I added breakup in dealloc methods of viewController. This is not called. Here is code to change rootViewController.

```
self.viewController = [[NSClassFromString(nextControllerName) alloc] initWithNibName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_iPhone",nextControllerName] bundle:nil];
[(BaseViewController *) self.viewController setEventKey:eventKey1];
[(BaseViewController *) self.viewController setControllerName:nextControllerName];
[(BaseViewController *) self.viewController setDataKey:dataKey];
[(BaseViewController *) self.viewController setTitleString:title];
[(BaseViewController *) self.viewController setTab:tab];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];    

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

I think some link is remaining in viewcontroller and appdelegate, so viewController is not deallocated. 
Please any help in finding leakage.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the UINavigationController? I don't think you need it.

Comment: That is required for showing camera, mail etc modally.

Comment: Does NSString* const or const float has problem? Means I need to set them to nil in dealloc?